# mask all users in a role

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

how can i mask value to all users of a role?
For example, i tried:

```
deny UNMASK TO public
```

now, all users can't see values.
but if i try to get grant to a user

```
GRANT UNMASK TO mask_user --is owner
```

this user still not see values.

Why?

My goal is to mask values also to onwer, except for some specific users.
**By default, owner are unmasked grant and could not be changed.**

```
create table mask_1
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    FirstName varchar(100)  MASKED WITH (Function = 'default()'),
    LastName varchar(100) MASKED WITH (Function = 'partial(1,"X",3)')
)

select *
from mask_1 t1
```

[image]

```
deny UNMASK TO public
```

[image]

```
GRANT UNMASK TO mask_user
```

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: DENY always overrides a GRANT. You don't need to specifically DENY a permission, just don't GRANT it in the first place to `public`.

Comment: hi, if i create a new owner user, i must sure it can't see value. i want deny all users by default, and allow only on request

Comment: To expand on @Charlieface's comment, if you start with a "clean" system then no-one has permissions on anything. You then have to explicitly grant permissions to users. So unless you have explicitly granted UNMASK to all users (or to a role that all users have, like PUBLIC) then a new user won't get it.

Comment: @NickW - no, is not true. owner users can see by default all masked values...try it please..

Comment: Owner users are, well, owners and can therefore give themselves whatever permissions they like. You need to make them *not* owners.

Comment: @Charlieface - i'm the client, i need give to developers grant as owner to develop db. but i don't want they can see my personal data.

Comment: So why do they need to be a DB owner? A DB owner can do *everything* including dropping the whole database. Just make them a regular user, and give them the roles they need such as `db_datareader` `db_datawriter` and `db_ddladmin` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670677/what-is-the-difference-between-being-a-db-owner-and-having-grant-all

Comment: yes sure, in production envirorment. but in dev envirorment they are free to do everything. they are not sysadmin and can't create users or change settings, but they need to create/truncate/restore/ecc. and i', looking to find the best way to manage my privacy.

Comment: If they can even directly get hold of backups then you are wasting your time, as anyone can just restore it to a different server on which they are `sa`. Best practice in this sort of situation is to give the devs sanitized or sample data upfront for them to test on.

Comment: Plus, if this is just for a Dev environment you obviously don’t have any “real” data - so what does it matter if your Devs can see the data unmasked?